# How to pack simple Python application?

Tags: python

I have a simple Python GUI application (with a standard structure, similar to https://github.com/kennethreitz/samplemod) it consists of several .py files in a subdirectory. I would like to send the folder with all the source code files to person B so he could easily run it.

- I need to zip the folder and transfer it on physical drive, so
  hosting on PyPI is not possible.
- Person B is likely to have python installed, but providing a simple way of
  how he can install dependencies would be nice. Person B might have
  Linux, Windows or MacOS.
- It is preferable for person B to be able to run the application in
  an easy way (preferably by running a script or few commands) that is
  considered a good-practice. I have read that for
  example altering PYTHONPATH is not a good practice.

Please explain in which format would YOU want to receive such application folder to be able to easily run it (consider that you want to run it once and then delete it and forget about it).

How should I prepare the application? What instructions should I give to person B?

Comment: You can always write script that will verify if all dependencies are meet, and install them if not. Second option is to "compile" this app and send it as exe file, in case when second person does not need access to source.
In first option just add bash or any similar script that will try to install all non standard packages, if some of them will be already installed then pip (easy_install) will skip them.

Comment: I would suggest writing OS based (bash for linux, batch or powershell for windows, etc.) scripts that will check for dependencies, install dependencies (with permissions), and "install" your python scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a file to your application that contains your dependencies (can be generated with pip freeze for instance). All of your dependencies can then be installed by pip install -r yourDependencyFile.txt

You can also easily make a bash-script or something similar for this that installs the dependencies and then starts the application. This will depend on your setup, but it could be as easy as

```
pip install -r dependencies.txt && python main.py
```